# Does Updating a Properties in a Sub-Collection Update the Main Collection?

Tags: c#

If I have two IEnumerable A and B, where B is a "sub-collection of A":

```
IEnumerable<Price> A = List of Price;
IEnumerable<Price> B = A.Where(x => x.Status == "N");
```

Will updating some properties of the Prices in B automatically update those same Prices and their properties in A?

```
foreach(var price in B)
{
   price.Date = DateTime.Now;
   price.Status = "F";
}
```

Will those same Prices in A that are in B now have their Date and Status properties updated?  If not, what's the best way to update them?  I already have an IEqualityComparer overriding the Equals and GetHashCode methods for something else.  Is there a quick way to update all Price properties of A with the Price properties from B for "Equal" Prices?

Comment: Short answer: If `Object` is actually a `class` of some type, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

If `Price` is a `class`, then the answer is: yes, when you modify an item in either collection it will be modified in the other. Any `class` derives from `object` which is a reference type.

However, if `Price` is actually a `struct`, then the answer is:
No, a value modified in one collection will not affect the other.  Structs are value types.

See also: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c#:%7E:text=You%20can%20imagine%20value%20type,clone%20the%20data%20in%20memory.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on)

Comment: Thank you! And yes, you are right, "Object" is a class type.  I edited the original post and changed "Object" to "Price".

Comment: @user3121062 Great, I updated the answer to reflect your changes.  If this answer was helpful, clicking the check mark would be appreciated!